# Browser - keeping color after remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know why this behavior in browser and how fix it.
When the class is removed the style keep in the element, until I click somewhere on the screen.

About one video explain the situation and link to see the behavior.

The link: https://www.santinidelivery.com/homologacao/

The video: https://youtu.be/lh4PTfdjuHI

The Snippet:

```
$.each( contentTop, function(i){
            if ( winTop > contentTop[i] - rangeTop ){
                $('.navbar-collapse li.scroll')
                .removeClass('active')
                .eq(i).addClass('active');          
            }
        })
```

Comment: remove `#navigation .navbar-right li a:focus` from `main.css` `line:354`

Comment: When you click on anchor tag it has focus and when you can on somewhere else element lose focus. you can apply css on focus element using `element:focus`.

Comment: Thank you! you resolve!